# React-Redux-Reducer - Same array element from api saving in the redux state when onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having a redux state in which i want to store data, which iam getting from an api, to display specific data on different pages. Here is my reducer code:

```
const INIT_STATE = {
  movies: [],
};

export const moviereducer = (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_MOVIE":
      return {
        movies: [action.payload],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I am having this hero component from which I am calling api and mapping the data, component code:

```
const Hero = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const Dispatch = useDispatch();

  const fetchData = () => {
    return axios
      .get("https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=all")
      .then((response) => setData(response.data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  console.log(data);

  const handleClick = (ele) => {
    Dispatch(ADD(ele));
  };

  return (
    <div className="heroWrap">
      <div className="cardWrap">
        {data &&
          data.map((ele, id) => {
            return (
              <Card key={id} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                <Card.Img variant="top" />
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{ele.show.name}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Text>Genres: {ele.show.genres + ","}</Card.Text>
                  <Button onClick={handleClick(ele)} variant="primary">
                    <Link className="text-white" to="/detail">
                      Read More
                    </Link>
                  </Button>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

No matter on which renderd item button I click on, it only save the same data in my redux state
Here is the data iam getting from api:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKzOA.png)

And here is what the state it saving:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDrbL.png)

**Edit: Since now i am able to store the exact state i want, Now i got a new problem, i am unable to render the image which i have stored in my redux state.**

My component in which i want to render the data:

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgb5z.png)

The data iam getting from my state:

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE4iS.png)

Comment: use `onClick={() =>handleClick(ele)}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

create anonymous function and call `handleClick` inside that.

```
<Button onClick={() => handleClick(ele)} variant="primary">
  <Link className='text-white' to='/detail'>Read More</Link>
</Button>
```

Comment: It worked thanks a lot, now its saving the exact state which I want

Answer (score 0):

Within your reducer you have to return the state which will be the state that is stored. In your case with your `ADD_MOVIE` action you return the state with `movies` as a property with the value of an array that contains one item which is the payload that is given to the action (by doing `[action.payload]`. I think what you want to do is navigate on click to a page that has the `id` or some other identifier in the url which you can get from the url and then using a selector select the specific movie you want with something like

```js
export function Component({ match }) {
  const id = match.params.id;

  const movie = useSelector(state => state.movies.find(movie => movie.id === id);

  // The rest of your component
```

if you are not using react router of course you can try to save the selected id in the store or something.